# Is there an expression to indicate the name of the layer on which the shape lies?

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap, expression

I have a question if there is an expression to indicate the name of the layer on which the shape lies.
Exactly what I mean:
I have a map created based on Open Street Map regarding public facilities like hospitals and schools. The polygons representing them (there are quite a few...) are located in different municipalities (33 to be exact).
Is there any way to indicate in the attribute table of a shape representing e.g. schools, that e.g. this school lies in municipality Y, and that school in municipality Y? In other words, is it possible to link data in such a way between two shapefiles?
I don't know if I expressed myself correctly...

[image: example of what I try to achieve...]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since QGIS 3.16 either:

```
array_first(overlay_intersects('layername of districts',"Field containing commune number"))
```

or

```
array_first(overlay_within('layername of districts',"Field containing commune number"))
```

In versions older than 3.16:

```
array_first(aggregate('layername of districts','array_agg',"Field containing commune number",filter:=intersects($geometry,geometry(@parent)))
```

*respectively replace `intersects()` with `within()`*

Comment: Thank you thank you thank you. I love this forum so much !

Comment: As a new user, please be adviced that this side tries to avoid "thank you" messages. Instead, it encourages you to accept the answer and/or upvote it: click the checkmark right to the answer to accept it - see: https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers
Just click the checkmark, see here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235